# Using Cosine Rule on Missing Included Side

Tags: trigonometry

While the Cosine rule itself is rather intuitive and easy to use, this seems to have been proven in cases where it is the OPPOSITE side that you are finding (as in, an angle and 2 included sides have been given and you are to find the side opposite the angle given).

However in a thought experiment and then coincidental in a homework question, i found myself having to solve for the side that was adjacent to the angle itself (as it, it was one of the included angles -- sides c or b if you will and still given angle A).

How would one find the included angle? I tried using the formula, however this just resulted in an ugly quadratic and made me feel that perhaps there was a better way. Is there a better way to approach these problems?

A some what clear example of my situation if you're still unclear: 
http://www.bbc.co.uk/staticarchive/a0c0cfaf4b19fb741ac485bf2104529fe7faa3cf.gif

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Sine Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines) to find $\angle C$, then use that the sum of angles in a triangle is $\pi$ to find $\angle B$, and finally the Sine Rule again to find side $b$. No need to use the Cosine rule at all.

Answer (score 0):

The standard rule of cosines for the known sides $b,c$ and $\angle A$ 
provides a value of the third side as

\begin{align}
a&=\sqrt{b^2+c^2-2bc\cos A} \tag{1}\label{1}
.
\end{align}
This rule always works
for any $b,c>0$ and $\angle A\in(0,180^\circ)$
it provides a unique value of $a$:
if we draw the given angle, mark two known sides
and join the ends, there always will be some valid triangle constructed.

Unfortunately,
situation is different when unknown side (for example, $c$) is adjacent to the angle. 
Let's try to construct a triangle as before: 
draw a horizontal line for the unknown side ($|AB|=c$),
draw the angle $A$, mark the side $|AC|=b$ 
and drop the altitude $h_c$ from $C$. 
Imagine that $\triangle AH_cC$ as a rigid construction
with the other segment of length $a$ attached to the point $C$
that can be rotated freely around $C$.
Clearly, there would be no solution, 
if $|CB|=a<h_c$, the side $|CB|$ 
would be just not long enough to intersect $AB$.
It is also obvious that in other cases there could be either one or two solutions.

[image]
[image]

The expression for the unknown side $c$ can be found 
as roots of quadratic equation \eqref{1} 
\begin{align}
c&=
b\,\cos A\pm\sqrt{(a+b\,\sin{A})(a-b\,\sin{A})}
\tag{2}\label{2}
.
\end{align}
Note that $b\,\sin A=h_c$, the altitude from vertex $C$, 
so we can rewrite \eqref{2} as

\begin{align}
c&=
b\,\cos A\pm\sqrt{(a+h_c)(a-h_c)}
\tag{3}\label{3}
.
\end{align}

Equations \eqref{2}-\eqref{3} provide plenty of information.

1) There is no valid solution in case $a<h_c$.

Otherwise:

2) There is one obvious solution when $\angle A=90^\circ$, namely $c=\sqrt{a^2-b^2}$.

3) Another single-valued solution happens when $a=h_c$ ($\angle B=90^\circ$), $c=b\,\cos A$.

4) There are two possible valid solutions 
if $b\,\cos A>\sqrt{(a+h_c)(a-h_c)}$

5) There is one valid solution that corresponds to the positive root
if $b\,\cos A<\sqrt{(a+h_c)(a-h_c)}$ and $\angle A<90^\circ$

6) We also need to consider the case $\angle A>90^\circ$ ($\cos A<0$). 
In this case we need to have $a>b$ in order to get a valid triangle.

Thus an innocent-looking change of accent in the initially available
information changes things dramatically.

Anyway, the Eqn. \eqref{2} provides two roots and
is all we need to figure out the solution, 
that is, if the two values are complex or both negative,
we have no solutions, otherwise we have either one or two positive solutions.

We can also use the sine rule, but then we have to take care of 
the fact that the other $\sin$ may have invalid value 
or correspond to two different angles ($\phi$ and $180^\circ-\phi$)
as well.